# Can android/iOS communicate through wifi

Tags: wifi, communication

I don't know how to explain what I want so I give example situation.

1. I got 3 smart phone, locate in 3 different room.
2. All room has a distance where wifi device A can Only communicate with B. But unable to C. So have to send to B and B send to C.

My question is do wifi can used for communication with different device?

How? Any tutorial?

My final finished project will required to work like wallow talkie through WIFI. Phone with wifi signal can listen and resend to another larger area.

Comment: What you should search in google is the term: [p2p over wifi](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your 'A, B C' scenario above, Phone 'B' can act as a wireless hotspot (even if it has no internet connection) and Phone A and Phone C can connect to it and speak to each other so long as they know each others IP address.

You would need to check the particular phones and OS version you are using supports this, but I have done with with several Android phones as an example.

I suspect, however, that your next question would be whether another phone, phone D, could then speak to A and B if it is only in range of Phone C.

This would require phone C to act as a wireless hotspot for phone D and at the same time as a wireless client to phone B's wireless hotspot. This is trickier and, while there are some example of an Android phone being used as a wireless repeater (e.g. http://www.littlegreenrobot.co.uk/tutorials/turn-your-android-device-into-a-wi-fi-extender/), I think you would need to experiment and I think you may find this won't work on most phones out of the box. When I tried a brief check using an Android phone running Android 4.3, turning the WiFi hotspot on automatically turns the WiFi access off.